# Media player with thumbnails over timeline

Tags: windows, gratis, media-player, thumbnail

Is there a media player (for desktop) that shows thumbnails of frames at different times like in most popular online videos players now a days?

I particularly like [youtube.com/tv](https://www.youtube.com/tv)'s version where seeking via keyboard left/right pops up a timeline of thumbnails at which the video will skip.

[image]

It should work on Windows. It should be gratis.

Comment: Paid or only free? If paid is OK, what's your limit?

Comment: That's very hard to find a free media player with thumbnail preview on the timeline / progress bar, still in 2020. VLC doesn't (really) want to add this feature. There was "Media Player Classic - Home Cinema" (MPC-HC) which had it, but it's not maintained anymore since 2017. Hopefully **Media Player Classic - BE** takes over, thank you laggingreflex, and thank you MPC-BE! Note: I add this comment  mostly to help next people searching this topic like me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Media Player Classic - BE](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mpcbe)

https://sourceforge.net/projects/mpcbe

[image: preview]

**You might need to enable the preview feature in the settings:**

[image: options]